# pluginPath and dependencies from remote p2 repositories

Tags: build, osgi, eclipse-pde, pde, p2

In my pde build I'm using `pluginPath` property to resolve dependencies from local p2 repositories for example:

> `DpluginPath=${basedir}/../../../plugins:/cache/3pp/site/mockito/1.8.2:/cache/3pp/site/spring/3.0.1`

I'm trying to find how to effectively materialize caches from HTTP p2 to local files.

I know that I could use `ant-contrib` for looping and invoke `p2.mirror` task for each dependency. Specially important is for me is minimalizing network overhead - to keep builds fast.

But, is the better way to declare dependency and materialize p2 repositories on local filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To feed p2 repositories into your build, you should place all of your repos in `repoBaseLocation`. Then by default `transformedRepoLocation` will be the runnable repo that is consumed by your build, and you shouldn't need to play with `pluginPath`.  See [Reusing Metadata](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_p2_reusingmetadata.htm).

How you get your repos into the `repoBaseLocation` is then up to you.  You could mirror stable repos into a common known location (a target directory outside of your current build directory) if they don't exist already, and have your build copy them into each `repoBaseLocation` per build.